# Kohana [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Image' not found

Tags: image-manipulation, kohana-3

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Image' not found.

i have created an image object:

```
$image = new Image($newFile);
$image = $image->resize(150, 150, Image::NONE);
$image->save($thumbsName);
```

it is giving the above mentioned error.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Instances in Kohana are created like this example :

```
$image = Image::factory('path/to/file.ext');
```

Also, uncomment the bootstrap.php line about the image module :

```
'image'      => MODPATH.'image',      // Image manipulation
```

Comment: Have you uncommented the bootstrap reference to Image?

Comment: Double check that you have Image module enabled in bootstrap and it really exists in setted directory.